# How to filter without using inbuilt function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

So I have an array which looks like the one displayed below:

```
const newTeachers = [
      { firstName: "Steve", subjects: ["English", "Maths", "History"] },
      { firstName: "Celia", subjects: ["Maths", "Science"] },
    ];
```

I want to create a function which takes in 2 parameters 1 being the array and 2nd being the filter string value.

```
function fliterSubject(teachers, subject) {

}
```

I have looked into the inbuilt way which is to implement this line of code:

```
 return newCandidates.filter(teacher=> teacher.subjects.includes(subject));
```

However I want to understand how I can filter it manually instead of using the inbuilt filter function.

Comment: Just iterate over it with `for` loop and if currently iterated element matches or unmatches the condition push it to new array or not.

Comment: You can loop through the array and push only if certain condition matches. but why you wanna do that ?

Comment: @CodeManiac I know there is the inbuilt filter function but I want to grasp the manual way of doing it to learn it.

Comment: It's good if you just wanna know how it works but in code it's preferable to use inbuilt one

Comment: @yes , I am just curious about it so am trying that way.

Comment: You can check in answer i have added a generic function for this and a bit explanation you can try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this.

```
var filterSubject = function(teachers, subject) {
  var filteredTeachers = [];
  for (var i=0; i<=teachers.length-1; i++) {
    var teacher = teachers[i];
    for (var j=0; j<=teacher.subjects.length-1; j++) {
      if (teacher.subjects[j].toLowerCase()== subject.toLowerCase()) {
        filteredTeachers.push(teacher);
      }
    }
  }
  return filteredTeachers;
}
```

Please check an example @ CodePen
https://codepen.io/animatedcreativity/pen/213ddd0a66b73b05c907da72c8aef3e3

Comment: why are you creating another var teacher. Is it because your are reading the array within teachers array right?

Comment: @sam251: `teacher` variable represents each teacher one by one in the `teachers` loop so that we can loop through all the subjects of each teacher and match with the supplied `subject` argument. If argument `subject` matches the teacher's subject in the loop, then that teacher is added to `filteredTeachers`.

Comment: I see that makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Explanation

You can achieve this with a simple for loop.

So you need to loop the array you're getting as argument in function.

Create a temporary array and push the values into it only if certain condition matches and return that array from function.

***So something like this :-***

```
function manuamMap(input, search){

Let temp = [];

for(let i=0; i<limit; i++) {
  if(some confition){
    temp.push();
  }
}

return temp
}
```